Use Chainlink VRF in another smart contract
I'm new to Solidity.
Currently I have a simple game like this:
Smart Contract:

Client:

Now I want to use randomness from Chainlink VRF:

How should I get random value from fulfillRandomWords to use in my Casino contract?

Thanks for your swift reply @SYED ASAD KAZMI. Let me clarify it a little bit more.

I have created a subscription and had the example contract: "contract VRFD20 is VRFConsumerBaseV2Plus" working. But I wonder is there a way to use the random value from this contract in my Casino contract instead of adding these logic of generating random into my Casino contract. I'd like to have 2 contracts: VRFD20 for generating random, and Casino for my game logic.
As you can see from my Casino contract ,there is a playGame function and at the end of it I emit RouletteGame event and my Client can listen to that right after calling playGame.
When using random from VRF here, function fulfillRandomWords  is a callback, I wonder how can my Client listen to the same event RouletteGame if I put it at the end of fuction fulfillRandomWords ?

--
I eventually get it work this way:

I deployed Chainlink VRF contract

I create an interface
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;
interface IVRF {
function getResult(uint256 roundId) external view returns
(uint256);
}

Then I can an instance in Casino constructor
vrfContract = IVRF(vrfContractAddress);

Then I interact with the deployed VRF contract through vrfContract instance



I eventually get it work this way:

I deployed Chainlink VRF contract

I create an interface
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;
interface IVRF {
function getResult(uint256 roundId) external view returns
(uint256);
}

Then I can an instance in Casino constructor
vrfContract = IVRF(vrfContractAddress);

Then I interact with the deployed VRF contract through vrfContract instance



Yes, you can use Chainlink VRF in order to consume the verifiable randomness on-chain. And, you can integrate that to any of your contract by:

Importing and inheriting the VRFConsumerBaseV2Plus contract and implementing the fulfillRandomWords() function.
Importing the VRFV2PlusClient library and sending request by calling the requestRandomWords() function using the instance of VRFCoordinatorV2_5 contract.
In case of Subscription Method, you need to add your deployed contract as a consumer to your subscription that you create on vrf.chain.link, and in case of Direct Funding Method, as the name suggests, you need to fund your contract with LINK or native tokens in order to request random values.

You can refer to this example of smart-contract-lottery contract utilizing the Chainlink VRF to select a random winner of the lottery.
The in-depth tutorial of the Raffle/Lottery contract consuming Chainlink VRF for verifiable randomness is available on Cyfrin Updraft as well as on YouTube.

Thanks for your swift reply. Let me clarify it a little bit more.

Got it. Yes, it's quite possible too. But, instead of posting that as an answer, kindly please delete that and add the same by editing your question itself. Also, it would be great if you can share the repo of your codebase, so that I can contribute to it wherever you face any problem or not sure about how to perform a certain functionality, you can add comments in your codebase accordingly.

In my contract, i am inheriting both VRFConsumerBaseV2Plus and ownable. this results in several conflicts, eg in "_transferOwnership" and "onlyOwner".
currently i am resolving these conflicts by deploying a standalone contract that requests random values from chainlink and hands them to my main contract.
is there any way to resolve these conflicts more smoothly?

VRFConsumerBaseV2Plus inherits the ConfirmedOwner, so you can utilize the "_transferOwnership()" function and "onlyOwner" modifier, just by inheriting VRFConsumerBaseV2Plus.

import the chainlink contract in your game contract and call the fulfillRandomWords  function
